# How to increasing Number of epoch in keras Conv Net

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Suppose, I have a model that is already trained with 100 epoch. I tested the model with test data and the performance is not satisfactory. So I decide to train for another 100 epoch. How can I do that?

I trained with 
model.fit(data, target, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size)

Now I want to train the same model without adding new data for another 100 epoch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Simply call `model.fit(data, target, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size)` again to carry on training the same model. `model` needs to be the same model object as in the initial training, not re-compiled.

Answer (score 0):

From Keras [webpage](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model):

Use `model.save()` to export your model in HDF5 format.

Later, import the model using `keras.models.load_model()`.

Then you can always `model.fit()` any saved / imported model to continue the training with either new samples when they become available or extra epochs on the previous training dataset.